# angular ng-model can't capture an onload input value

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, geolocation

I'm using a window onload script to capture long and lat and pass them to hidden input value.

```js
$(function() {
  window.onload = getLocation;
  var geo = navigator.geolocation;

  function getLocation() {
    if (geo) {
      geo.getCurrentPosition(displayLocation);
    } else {
      alert("Oops, Geolocation API is not supported");
    }
  }

  function displayLocation(position) {
        var lang = position.coords.longitude;
    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
    console.log(lat);
    document.getElementById('txtlat').value = lat;
    document.getElementById('txtlang').value = lang;
  }


});
```

Then I try to capture the value of those input with angular `ng-model` but it doesn't seem to work. It's like it's empty and it doesn't know input fields are filled any ideas how to fix it?

```js
//controller of the register html
$scope.user = {};

$scope.register = function(form) {
      $scope.submitted = true;

      if (form.$valid) {
        Auth.createUser({
          name: $scope.user.name,
          email: $scope.user.email,
          password: $scope.user.password,
          lang: $scope.user.lang,
          lat: $scope.user.lat
        })
        .then(function() {
          // Account created, redirect to home
          $state.go('main');
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
          err = err.data;
          console.log(err);
          $scope.errors = {};

          // Update validity of form fields that match the mongoose errors
          angular.forEach(err.errors, function(error, field) {
            form[field].$setValidity('mongoose', false);
            $scope.errors[field] = error.message;
          });
        });
      } else {
        console.log("form not work")
      }
      console.log($scope.user);
    };
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<form class="form" name="form" ng-submit="register(form)" novalidate>
  <input type="text" name="txtlang" class="form-control" id="txtlang" ng-model="user.lang">
  <input type="hidden" name="txtlat" class="form-control" id="txtlat" ng-model="user.lat">
  <button class="btn btn-inverse btn-lg btn-register" type="submit">
  Sign up</button>
</form>
```

When I try to register, input values won't get captured and saved unless I modify the input value after the default capture done by the onload function if that makes sense ?

Comment: There's nothing about angularjs in this question, where's the angular part?

Comment: the part where I use ng-model to capture the input fields ? :) {{ <input  type="text" name="txtlang" class="form-control" id="txtlang"  ng-model="user.lang"> }} should have wrote this part to make it clearer i guess sorry

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43711016/edit) your question and add it there, no harm done :)

Comment: ok I just did thanks

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the coordinates using the device's GPS, you need to create a factory that return a promise that resolves with the current coordinates, or reject in case there is an issue.

Take a look at this:

```js
angular.module('app', []).service( 'geo', ['$q', function($q) {
  return {
    getLocation: function() {
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      if( !navigator.geolocation ) {
        // geolocation is not available, 
        // better just reject the promise and return it :(

        deferred.reject( "Oops, Geolocation API is not supported" );
        return deferred.promise;
      }
      
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
        function (pos) {
           // We have your position!
           deferred.resolve(pos);
        }, 
        function (error) {
           // Oh no! We can't get your position
          deferred.reject(error);
        }, {
          // Some setings 
          enableHighAccuracy: false,
          timeout: 5000,
          maximumAge: 0
        }
      );

      return deferred.promise
    }
  };
}]).controller('ctrl', ['$scope', 'geo', function( $scope, geo ) {
  geo.getLocation().then(
    function( pos ) {
      $scope.coordinates = pos.coords;
      console.log(pos);
    },
    function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  );
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <div>
    <strong>latitude:</strong><span ng-bind="coordinates.latitude"></span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <strong>longitude:</strong><span ng-bind="coordinates.longitude"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

I created a `factory` named `geo` that return an object with a single property `getLocation`- That is a function that return a promise that resolve with the coordinates.

Inside the controller I'm injecting the factory and using it to get the location using `geo.getLocation()` and in the promise i'm saving the location that was passed to the promise.

I couldn't run this code in SO's snippet so I created a working example here: https://jsfiddle.net/3Ln19j68/

Comment: interesting Alon, how would you pass this data to your server to an existing mongo schema tho ?

Comment: @ben I have no idea, don't know anything about mongo and you didn't asked about it in your question. I suggest opening a new question if you can't manage it yourself (But basically you need [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) for that)

Comment: https://embed.plnkr.co/eNxt5cmPraP4rzc3bxNg/

this is what I'm trying to do, get long/lat from onload window, then pass it to my controller from the factory and save it but I struggle with the ng-bind expression and how to save it in the controller, I'm at loss

Comment: @ben Basically, on `controlergeoservice.js` you need to change `longitude: $scope.user.Geoposition.coordinates.longitude,` with `longitude: $scope.coordinates ? $scope.coordinates.longitude : null,` and the same with `latitude`

Answer (score 0):

Not really too familiar with jquery... but I think the problem is you're modifying an Angular input outside of Angular, so it has no idea that the input has changed.

What you should do is wrap your non-angular code with $scope.$apply, then angular will know that the input has changed. Something like:

```
$scope.$apply(function() {
    document.getElementById('txtlat').value = lat;
    document.getElementById('txtlang').value = lang;
});
```

See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply for more information on $apply/$digest cycle.